# Chart js label font color not changing

Tags: javascript, charts, colors, chart.js, settings

I have a pie graph in my web application and above the graph there are labels with names next to them. The text is very hard to read due to the color.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/C2SX6.png) I really want to change the text color, but for some reason I can't.

I tried:

1. Turning off extentions on chrome.
2. Changing browser.
3. Using extra css style(down)
4. Checked css for global styles, I have only these(also down)

I need to solve this till the end of today, I would be really thankful for your help.
Thanks!

My expectations are just to being able to change the font color, nothing more nothing less

The code:

```
    <script>
        var ctx = document.getElementById('expenseChart').getContext('2d');
        
        var data = {
            labels: [
                {% for expense in expenses_by_type %}
                    "{{ expense.place_type }}"{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
                {% endfor %}
            ],
            datasets: [{
                data: [
                    {% for expense in expenses_by_type %}
                        {{ expense.total_amount }}{% if not forloop.last %}, {% endif %}
                    {% endfor %}
                ],
                backgroundColor: [
                    'rgb(241,169,12)',
                    'rgb(233,116,24)',
                    'rgb(236,138,20)',
                    'rgb(227,71,36)',
                    'rgb(228,95,28)',
                    'rgb(220,49,43)',
                    'rgb(236,153,12)',
                    'rgb(243,185,4)',
                    'rgb(228,84,28)',
                ],
            }]
        };

        var options = {
            responsive: true,
            maintainAspectRatio: false,
            legend: {
                display: true,
                labels: {
                    fontColor: 'white',
                },
            },
        };



        var myPieChart = new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'pie',
            data: data,
            options: options,
        });
    </script>
```

```
    <style>
        #expenseChart .chartjs-render-monitor .chartjs-legend {
            color: white !important;
        }
    </style>
```

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-family: 'Bricolage Grotesque', sans-serif;
}
```

Comment: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/general/colors.html#color-formats - doesn't say you could use color _names_ such as `white` there.

Comment: Using rgb, rgba or HEX doesn't work as well. Also, using fontSize didn't work either, so maybe the issue is something bigger than just syntax error idk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You defined your legend options in the wrong place. It should be in the plugins namespace, also `fontColor` does not exist anymore, you need to define `font.color`

```js
options: {
  plugins: {
    legend: {
      labels: {
        font: {
          color: 'red'
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```